# IPhone 5 Compatible application using xcode 4.3.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, iphone-5

I have completed my universal application using xcode 4.3.3 but when I run application in iPhone 5 , my application launches in small screen. I also changed the launched image to `Default-568h@2x.png` but all in vein. Please help me out , How can i make application for iPhone 5 using `xcode 4.3.3`?

Comment: You will need to update your Xcode since you need iOS 6 SDK, which came with Xcode 4.5

Comment: any other way that i can add iphone 5 compatibility in xcode 4.3.3?

Comment: No, you need iOS 6 SDK thus must upgrade your Xcode. Is there any valid reason why you can't update you Xcode version?

Comment: yes , the reason is my mac is not compatible with mac 10.8 , thats why i am unable to upgrade my xcode :/

Comment: Then you are out of luck, you need OSX lion and Xcode 4.5 to target iOS 6. There is not other option. Most macs can run OSX 10.7 you do not need 10.8

Comment: helpless situation, why don't you update your mac? I think you are currently on snowleopard..is it?

Comment: @MilKyWaY No, Snow Leopard only supports Xcode 4.2, so he must be running Lion, which can run Xcode 4.6 without problem.

Comment: i am on OSX 10.7.5 , is xcode 4.5 available for 10.7.5?

Comment: @trojanfoe oopz..parden..I didn't notice that

Comment: dude, your OS X Lion is compatible with xcode 4.5, why don't you upgrade your xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to target iOS 6 with Xcode 4.3.3 you need to update to Xcode 4.5 or higher.
To run Xcode 4.5 or higher your mac will need to running OSX lion or higher.